# Struggling with view results

Tags: views

I'm struggling with view results. This is the first time I've ever posted on one of these! I set up a view to filter responses from a survey on a webform. The responses are supposed to show up if one required question is marked true. The other filters are exposed.

The problem is that the results do not show up correctly. Two of the results are included twice, and after a certain date, none of the results are included. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Set query option distinct so that results are included just once

[image]

and check your filter criteria, maybe you included some date condition.